# Web Crypto API sha-224

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

In one of the draft version of the specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-WebCryptoAPI-20130625/) I did found references to the `sha-224` algorithm but, it seems it did not make it in final version (https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/).

Is there a way to generate a `sha-224` with the Web Crypto API?